# How to render Minecraft on the GPU?

Tags: 12.04, graphics, radeon, minecraft

Hardware:

- Intel i7
- AMD Radeon HD 6970
- SSD with plenty of space
- 6 GB RAM

Software

- OpenJDK 6, 7, and Oracle Java 7 (reproducible with all three)
- AMD Catalyst 12.8 and open source driver (reproducible with both)
- Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 and older
- Minecraft 1.3.2 vanilla and older

On this setup I am getting rubbish frame rates after a short while of playing, dropping from about 45-55 to 15 in a couple of minutes. CPU use is 40-45 even when rendering the opening screen at 1920x1280, and gameRenderer is using about 90% CPU when playing.

Rather than trying to eke out a few more FPS out of an obviously broken rendering pipeline, I really hope to find a solution to **make the *GPU* render Minecraft**.

Edit 1: Something bizarre just happened: The first thing I always change in the settings is to turn bobbing off. Turns out that **re-enabling bobbing** makes the frame rate shoot right back up from 15-20 to 30-50 (mostly around 30) in fullscreen mode! It is still rather erratic, bumping down to 15-20 sometimes, but usually only for a few seconds.  Also, the debug mode (<kbd>F3</kbd>) shows that 100% of the time is spent in "unspecified".

Edit 2: That seems to have been a dud - I disabled bobbing again a few minutes later, and it's been running at 20-40 FPS since. The snooper reports 24 FPS.

Comment: AFAIK, minecraft is way more dependent on the CPU than the GPU. On that note, have you tried out [optifine](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.minecraftforum.net%2Ftopic%2F249637-132-optifine-hd-b3-fps-boost-hd-textures-aa-af-and-much-more%2F&ei=bhNqUOvfNonZsgbFnYFY&usg=AFQjCNElTGYGQaFAi5N2Unwpe7ekISGKBQ)? It's supposed to increase FPS significantly.

Comment: Minecraft uses LWJGL, a Java gaming library which run atop OpenGL.  So, assuming your graphics card driver has full support for OpenGL under Ubuntu, it should already be rendering with the GPU.  Aside from Optifine *(and trying the 32-bit JVM - minecraft has issues under the 64-bit JVM in some setups)*, the only thing you can really do is turn down the render-distance.

Comment: @Glutanimate With optifine it got a lot *worse*: 10-11 FPS even after turning off advanced OpenGL and setting tiny render distance.

Comment: @l0b0 There are many Optifine editions available, start by chosing the multithreaded shaderless version and edit the configuration until your FPS increases. Optifine versions are not generic, you should read the author's documentation to match a specific Optifine version with a specific Minecraft version; the same for Forge. Hope you solve, bye.

Answer (score 0):

Check the amount of memory allocated allotted for mc to use; if its running in 32 bit mode it will only show max 2 or 3gb, if 64 bit mode how ever much memory you have - 1gb will be shown (option is only available in the launcher).

If your running a mod pack 4 gb is the max you will need. If its running 32 and you already have 64 then you have to uninstall 32 (there might be a fix,, I just don't know one). It is not sensible to run a 32 bit system with 6gb RAM + graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall *Oracle Java*.

I had the same problem  (but with an even better GPU) and had the same Java installs, I removed Oracle and my fps shot up from 20fps to 200fps. 10 times better than before.

Or you can right click on it and run with open JDK to see if it's the Java or the GPU.

Also use the catalyst driver modules for your graphic card.

Comment: Could you provide instructions for that?

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft doesn't use the GPU for most of its calculations, instead relying solely on the CPU. This results in some pretty trash performance. But, since these calculations are hard coded into the game, there really is no way to change them, and completely change the component that the game is run on. Doing so would require them to rewrite the entire game.